# Plugin in still active even though it's been deactivated and deleted

Tags: plugins, images, deactivated-plugin

I am testing out a no-right click plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-content-copy-protector/

But I didn't like the look of it, so deactivated it and deleted but it still shows up on the website, what else can I do to remove this?

Thank you!

Comment: If the plugin really is gone, that means that either 1) you have caching on your site and you're still looking at the cached version; or 2) it's edited itself into your posts somehow, and it lives on in your database. But I assume there's some script involved, so I doubt it's 2.